# Align left element to fit free space

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. Div that must be on the right side, must have fixed width and left one must fit free space. I can't achieve this effect, but I have done oposite of this case, when left one is fixed and right one is stretched:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="part left"></div>
    <div class="part right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.part {
    height: 100px;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

.right {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9NKyq/). Can you help? (I want to do it without using `calc`, because the width of right div may change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit your markup with the right-floated div first.

```
<div>
    <div class="part right"></div>
    <div class="part left"></div>
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9NKyq/1/)**

### CSS (like your original)

```
.part {
    height: 100px;
}

.right {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
}

.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried exact same but probably I missed something

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use flexbox.
It's exactly what you need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Use absolute positioning and padding-right.

```
code
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ak8Xb/1/